# Print exit() output to stderr in PHP

Tags: php, stderr

The following code

```
<?php
exit("where");
?>
```

prints the word `where` to `stdout`.

How to print `exit()` output to `stderr`?

Answer (score 5):

Just do:

```
fprintf(STDERR, "where");
exit();
```

Comment: I know, but the question was a curiosity about `exit()`. Think if you have a large legacy code base with lot of output and you want to catch only errors on stderr, let’s say, to send it via mail. And what about the pattern `$db->query() or die(...)`? Bad practice or not, it is used very often with many common database libraries (mysql, mysqli, PDO), shown in examples and in books...